# svn: trying to commit after remove a folder and create it again (with the same name)

Tags: svn

imagine i have made a co. Then I remove a folder inside the code I have checkout and create another one with the same name. Then if i try to commit I get:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Directory '/opt/lampp/htdocs/prueba4/apps/frontend/modules/moto/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing
laptop@laptop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/prueba4$ sudo svn st
~       apps/frontend/modules/moto
```

If i tried to add that folder i get:

```
svn: warning: 'apps/frontend/modules/moto' is already under version control
```

What should i do?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete that folder, checkout/update to make old folder appear, and after that do all stuff you want but via SVN client :)

Comment: what does "do all stuff you want via svn client" mean?

Comment: I mean further deletion of folder/addition of folders/and so on. You should never delete or move files, which are under version control, directly.

Comment: Just to clarify Nickolay`s answer: use `$ svn delete folder` instead of `$ rm folder`